# How should look the URL to GET the JSON String

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

Why with first String the "jsonGetMethod" method works, but with second and third Strings - does not? When I'm inputting the URL from all the Strings in Android Web-Browser - I see the json response. (I'm using Eclipse, Real Android Device(not emulator) connected by Wi-Fi to internet, in the AndroidManifest Internet Permission is added.)

```
    //This String works fine
    private static String url = "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld";

    //Log.d(jsonStr) shows "null"
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.200:8080/test/json";

    //Exception throws
    private static String url = "192.168.1.200:8080/test/json";

    public String jsonGetMethod(String url) 
    {
        try {

          DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
          HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

          HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
          httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


          httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
          response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
}

String jsonStr = jsonGetMethod(url);
Log.d(jsonStr);
```

Comment: Port number is different, for http port default number is 443

Comment: Your third url is invalid. It's missing `http://`

Comment: Do you have a webserver on this(192.168.1.200) machine? Is it configured right? Are you able to call the service via a browser?

Comment: I understood about the "port" and "http:", but are they required? What if I want to use port "8080"?

Comment: I see the jSON strings in the web-browser of Android Tablet.

Comment: Check the logcat. My guess is an exception is being thrown and one of your `catch` blocks will be writing the stacktrace the log.

Comment: @Squonk - Yes. But now the problem is port. How to adapt the code to port "8080"?

Comment: As long as your web server is listening on port 8080 it will work.

Comment: @Squonk - It does not. I think, I have to change something.

Comment: @user922907 : The port number is set at the server - it doesn't matter what it is as long as your URL uses the same one.

Comment: @Squonk - I understood that, but may be "httpGet" does not allowing port number in URL?

Comment: @user922907 : Yes it does - it's a standard URL format that I use myself. `http://<numeric-ip-address>:<port-number>/`. There's no reason why your URL of `http://192.168.1.200:8080/test/json` should fail with `HttpGet` unless your server isn't configured on that IP address and port or you have a firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: @Squonk - Should it work if I'm using the Async Class when splitting my Json after receiving? "private class myMethod extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>"

Comment: @user922907 : YEs, it's quite usual to use an `AsyncTask` to get data from a web server using the `doInBackground` method and either process it there or pass the result to `onPostExecute` for processing.